# Grunt "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, gruntjs, npm

```
    pm WARN EPACKAGEJSON partnerportal@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON partnerportal@0.0.0 No license field.
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-autoprefixer" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-concurrent" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-filerev" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-google-cdn" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-karma" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-newer" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-ng-annotate" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-svgmin" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-usemin" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-wiredep" not found. Is it installed?
    Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'time-grunt'
```

New to **NPM** and **grunt**. Not sure exactly whats going on? Any ideas how to debug? installed **NPM** and **BOWER**

Comment: It seems that `grunt` is trying to load `time-grunt`, but the package cannot be found in *node_modules*. Two things you can do: (1) If you have a *package.json* file, it may have a number of dependencies specified, so just run `npm install` in the same directory to download those dependencies into your *node_modules* directory; (2) to install individual modules, such as `time-grunt`, you can do `npm install time-grunt --save-dev`.

Comment: What's in your Gruntfile.js?

Comment: updated my Gruntfile.js in question

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I updated the script to do nam install time-grunt, Now its complaining about > Error: Cannot find module 'jshint-stylish'. Does it have to do anything with the path as none nam modules are being loaded. I am not sure if the path is correctly set?

Comment: @upagna Notice the line `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`. What that does is look inside *package.json* for declared dependencies. If you don't do `npm install`, those dependencies may be missing, so grunt won't be able to find them. First, it was`time-grunt` plugin that was missing, now it's `jshint-stylish`. You just need to install all of the dependencies by running `npm install`.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan Did the Npm install. .It ran. But now its not able to do the dist task for grunt !!!

Comment: @upagna What "dist task" are you referring to? I don't see any dist tasks. A number of tasks (such as clean, for example) have a dist declaration, but there is no dist task.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan  This was the error .Warning: Task "dist" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings. This was the error . These were the warnings npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g

Comment: @upagna Are you just running "grunt" or a specific task?

Comment: I am trying to do   grunt dist ..Trying to create a dist directory  @hunan Rostomyan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96405/discussion-between-hunan-rostomyan-and-upagna).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that, you was not run `npm install` to install all packages for your project before running `grunt`. In the normal case, to build a Grunt App. We should run by the steps below:

Install NPM packages.

```
cd to_root_project_path

npm install
```

Install Bower packages

```
bower install
```

Finally, run grunt tast

Answer (score -1):

Also sometimes sudo with npm install grunt fixes the issue too

`sudo npm install grunt`

Comment: This might resolve the issue, or it might not, but it doesn't really help the asker understand what is going on or how to debug, which is the question at hand.